# JavaScript automatic type conversion + loops

Tags: javascript

A noob with a problem here.

Scenario 1:

```
do { var yourName = prompt("Who are you?"); } while (!yourName); console.log(yourName);
```

Returns a string if something was typed into the prompt box.
If you didn't type anything and click "OK", it continues to ask for name. And if you click "Cancel", it still continues to ask.

Scenario 2:

```
do { var yourName = prompt("Who are you?"); } while (yourName != true); console.log(yourName);
```

Keeps asking for a name even if you type something or click "OK" or "Cancel". It just gets stuck. Infinite loop?

In scenario 1 the program works like this:
Do this (ask for name) while yourName is false (false meaning undefined). If yourName gets a defined value console.log the name.
I know that an empty string ("") is converted in boolean value as false. And i also know that it is converted from false to true because of ! before being negated by ! from true back to false. So if the program is getting the empty string by clicking "OK" or "Cancel", it is getting the original false, converted to true and then the converted true is negated by ! back to false, and that's why it is keeping asking for a name for as long as you don't type it. And when you type in something, the typed value is true, it gets checked by !, we get back true and it is being console.logged.

In scenario 2 the program works almost like in 1st case but it doesn't accept any typed values because when you type in something, it is true in boolean, true != true will give us false so it will ask for name again. But here is what i don't understand about 2nd case: when you click "OK" or "Cancel", they are translated as false, and false != true is true, which should pass and console.log the empty string.

I think i understood something wrong or...i don't even know. Please explain me this guys.

Also this is quiet strange too:

```
do { var yourName = prompt("Who are you?"); } while (typeof(yourName) != true); console.log(yourName);
```

And

```
do { var yourName = prompt("Who are you?"); } while (typeof(yourName) != false); console.log(yourName);
```

Comment: Am I the only one who has never used a `do while` in "real life"? :D

Answer (score 2):

**Scenario 1:**

**Cancel** returns `null` and **OK** returns empty `""`, and both satisfies `!yourName`.

Instead just check if user has clicked **cancel** or not by adding a condition `yourName != null`

**Demo**

```js
do {
  var yourName = prompt("Who are you?");
} while (!yourName && yourName != null);
console.log(yourName);
```

**Scenario 2:**

**OK** doesn't return **boolean** so `yourName != true` will never fail - hence the infinite loop in this scenario as well.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `!yourName`, the empty string `''` is falsy and a non-empty string is truthy, so the boolean condition is true.

When you use `yourName != true`, both operands are converted to a number and then compared: [loose comparison with `==`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness#Loose_equality_using). This means that comparing the string `'1'` to `true` evaluates to true.

```js
console.log("'' and true:", +'', +true);
console.log("'your name' and true:", +'your name', +true);
console.log("'true' and true:", +'true', +true);
console.log("'1' and true:", +'1', +true);
```

This is one of those places that JavaScript is just out to get you. It is quite commonly accepted to use `!yourName`, but being explicit with `(yourName != null && yourName != '')` will not hurt.